# Iterate on available control and check if this are enabled

Tags: vb.net

I want iterate on GroupBox controls and check if the `CheckBox` are Checked or not. Actually I'm stuck on this:

```
For Each c In User.GroupBox3.Controls

        If c.GetType.Name = "CheckBox" Then

          If c.Checked = True ..?               

        End If

    Next
```

How you can see I can't access to `.Checked` property, someone know how can I figure out?

Comment: Are all the controls in `User.GroupBox3` checks?

Comment: They *can* hold other controls, you are checking the Type name is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about `Types`.  `CheckBox` is a Type, which inherits from `Control` which is another Type.  Since a `ControlsCollection` holds the items as `Control`, you have to cast to the specific Type in order to access the more specific properties and methods:

#### Long Form:

```
 For Each c As Control In TabPage1.Controls
    ' check if it is the Type we are looking for
    If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then
        ' convert to desired type, do something
        CType(c, CheckBox).Checked = True
    End If
Next
```

`CType` converts/casts from `Control` to `CheckBox`.

#### Short Form:

```
For Each c As CheckBox In TabPage1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
    c.Checked = True
Next
```

This version filters to a given Type so the cast isnt needed.